# Using GitHub on Windows Vista 32-bit machine

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, github-for-windows

I'm trying to configure GitHub based on [https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/]. 
while executing the following command:
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Googled for same and found solution to execute the following (is also throwing error):
$ eval ssh-agent -s
      0 [main] ssh-agent 4708 fork_copy: linked dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0xC5
D000..0xC63070, done 0, windows pid 4792, Win32 error 87
fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

Clone command is also not working. Can some one help.

Comment: Do you have a running ssh-agent.exe process when you launch Git Shell?

Comment: No. I dont have it running.

Comment: What output do you get when you run `ssh-agent` from the shell?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Cloning repo into local doesn't depend on the 'add' or 'eval' commands.
All we have to do is click on the 'fork' button in GitHub and save project under username.

Execute "git clone SSH URL" to create a local repo.